# How to remove one of two domains on the same site for SEO?

Tags: seo, multiple-domains

I have foo.com which is set up as the alias of bar.com
For better ranking etc I want search engines to only crawl foo.com
How do I "remove" bar.com ?

Is it the same method as removing www (which I'll also be using) ? if so what's the code ?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to 301 Redirect all requests for `bar.com` (or `www.bar.com` or `www.foo.com`) to `foo.com` using `.htaccess` or a similar method. Google will tell you how, or there are a [few questions on this site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htaccess?sort=votes).

You can also tell Google of a "change of address" through Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: If google told everything stackexchange wouldn't exist. I found several example code to do each redirects but since I don't know mod_rewrite I don't know what the differences mean nor how to combine rules.